# gfortran returns error in compiling

Tags: compilation, gfortran, intel-fortran

I try to install a program called "Wavewatch III" but it returns 2 errors in log files and one in output display when I try to make it:

log:

```
gfortran: error: big_endian: No such file or directory
gfortran: error: unrecognized option ‘-convert’
```

Display:

```
gfortran: error: language SSE4.2 not recognized
```

by the way when I switch the compiler to "ifort" instead of "f95" it returnes many more errors! I also have ifort and f95 installed on my machine which is Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Any idea?

Comment: For the first part, you possibly want -fconvert=big-endian as a compile option instead of "-convert big_endian" or whatever is there.

Answer (score 0):

Please see gfortran documentation: [relevant documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Runtime-Options.html). The compilation command that works is

```
 gfortran hello.f90 -fconvert=big-endian -xSSE4.2
```